# Insert thousands of records from .NET datatable into Sybase

Tags: c#, .net, sap-ase

What is the efficient way of inserting thousands of records from .NET datatable into sybase enterprise database ?. Are there any bulk insert options or should i stick with batch insert ?.

Answer (score 1):

Since your tags appear to indicate you're looking for a .NET solution, I'd suggest looking at `Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseBulkCopy`.

It's very similar to `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy`.

Comment: read about AseBulkCopy and it seems much slower than ODBC operations.

Comment: What i need to do is load thousands of records from datatable into Sybase db tables. Previous developer is passing xml doc created from dt to stored procedures in batches. Sybase varchar max can only take up to 16000 characters doing this way is taking bit of time to do that. Any better ways to do?..